# How to sign up for android developer on play store with debit cards in India?

Tags: android, paypal, google-play, android-pay

Location . India.
I want to sign up for android developer on play store but I don't have any credit cards but I have debit cards . How to do it with debit cards any way of doing it. ?

Answer (score 0):

Integerate Debit Card with Paypal and pay Developers on play store via Paypal.

Comment: I'll try immediately.